# Why is my jquery toggle not working

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Here why my toggle is not working

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tab").hide()
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $("#tab").toggle();
        }) 
     })       
</script>
```

**Html Code**

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <b>Employee Name</b>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="Emp in John">
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn1" value="click" />
                {{Emp.Name}}
                <table id="tab">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <b>OrderId</b>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="Joy in Emp.order">
                        <td>
                            {{Joy.OrderId}}

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please check this?? you are having ng-repeat , means a loop and you can have multiple elements with the same id which can cause issue.

Comment: Works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/zjk02e6d/  Do you have code which actually demonstrates the problem?

Comment: not working above code

Comment: @WaheedMohammad: "Above code" was copied and pasted *verbatim* to jsFiddle and *demonstrably* works.  Try again.  Or maybe you could take at least a moment of your time and describe the problem more clearly.  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.  "Not working" isn't a description of a problem.

Comment: Why to use jQuery at the first place, doh...

Answer (score 0):

Rather you should use ng-click and give unique id to each of your elments jus like below.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <b>Employee Name</b>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="Emp in John track by $index">
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="btn1{{$index}}" value="click"  ng-click="toggel($index)"/>
                {{Emp.Name}}
                <table id="tab{{$index}}">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <b>OrderId</b>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr ng-repeat="Joy in Emp.order">
                        <td>
                            {{Joy.OrderId}}

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And you can write angular js funciton to do the toggle effect. Just like below

```
$scope.toggel = function(index){
$("#tab"+index).toggle();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a few semi-colons. Might be why.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tab").hide();
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $("#tab").toggle();
        }); 
     });       
</script>
```